# Pyrhon. Поиск и экспорт

Tags: python, импорт, hex, export

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать через скрипт питона:

Нужно написать скрипт, который будет считывать один hex файл и вытаскивать из него в текстовый файл 4 байта после "00 00 00 00". Но эти 4 байта нужно также перевернуть и сконвертировать в decimal.

Например вот кусок из этого файла

07 00 04 01 00 01 03 d2 91 01 00 05 50 00 00 00 00 a3 b8 54 77 d9 70 00 00 ca e9 00 00 ff ff ff ff a3 b8 54 77 91 00 a2 00 01

Скрипт ищет "00 00 00 00", находит, и после них нужно вытащить 4 байта:

a3 b8 54 77

Но их надо перевернуть:

77 54 b8 a3

И преобразовать в dec

Получится: 2002040995

И все полученные числа записать в текстовый файл.

Comment: В чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: Написать скрипт, который будет вытаскивать из hex файла в текстовый файл все значения (4 байта), которые идут после "00 00 00 00".

Comment: Вот побольше текста из файла: 07 00 04 01 00 01 03 d2 91 01 00 05 50 00 00 00 00 a3 b8 54 77 d9 70 00 00 ca e9 00 00 ff ff ff ff 53 00 d5 07 91 00 a2 00 01. Нужно вытащить 4 байта после 00 00 00 00

Comment: Вы не знаете как код ниже реализовать с файлами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input_file_name = 'in.bin'
out_file_name='num.txt'

with open(input_file_name, 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()

count_of_zeros = 0
count_of_bytes = 0

res=[]                                              #Список для четырех байт
allres=[]                                           #Список для списков из четырех байт

for el in s:
    if count_of_bytes <= 3 and count_of_zeros == 4:  #Пока кол-во байт меньше 4 и найденно 4 нуля подряд
        res.append(el)                               #складываем в список байты
        count_of_bytes+=1                            #считаем до четырех
    else:
        if count_of_bytes==4:                        #Когда собрали 4 байта
            allres.append(res)                       #Забираем и обнуляемся
            res=[]
            count_of_bytes=0
            count_of_zeros=0
        if el == 0:                                  # Считаем нули подряд
            count_of_zeros += 1
        else:
            count_of_zeros = 0


dec_number=0
st_out=''
for al in allres:
    for i,n in enumerate(al):
        dec_number+= n * 256 ** i                   #Подсчитываем десятичное число
    if dec_number!=0:
        st_out+= str(dec_number) + '\n'
    dec_number=0

with open(out_file_name,'w') as out_file:           #Записываем в файл
    out_file.write(st_out)
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143059/discussion-on-answer-by-oopss-pyrhon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.